# i want to play mp3 with QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to use QmediaPlayer for playing .wav file
but when i use demo code,it does't work,i can't hear any voice
This is demo code

```
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
file = QUrl.fromLocalFile(r'F:\Cloudmusic\test.mp3') # filepath
player=QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(file)
player.setMedia(content)
player.setVolume(50.0)
player.play()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My OS is windows,and get no error message

I run it in terminal,and got some message:

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen DPI.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unknown error 0x80040266.
```

Comment: Is player.play() asynchronous? Maybe try delaying 10+ seconds before running `sys.exit` is the solution?

Comment: Your example WORKS.

Comment: Try to run the program from a terminal/prompt and see if it gives you any warning: I just tried your code (I only changed the path to an existing file) and it works.

Comment: install codecs: https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm

Comment: Thanks,install codecs can solve  this problem